# How to combine two nested tuples and use in Django's CharField choices?

Tags: python, django, nested, tuples

I have two nested tuples similar to the ones below which will be used in [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) in Django's [model.CharField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#charfield).

```
COMPANIES = (
    ('USA', (
          ('gm', 'General Motors'), 
          ('tesla', 'Tesla'),
          ('ford', 'Ford')
        )
    ),
    ('South Korea', (
          ('kia', 'Kia Motors'),
          ('hyundai', 'Hyundai Motors'),
        )
    ),
    ('Japan', (
          ('nissan', 'Nissan Motors'),
          ('honda', 'Honda Motors'), 
          ('toyota', 'Toyota Motors'), 
        ) 
    ),
)

MANAGERS = (
    ('USA', (
          ('jack', 'Jack Smith'), 
          ('doyun', 'Doyun Kim'),
          ('jill', 'Jill Maggie'),
          ('akari', 'Akari Tanaka'),  
        )
    ),
    ('South Korea', (
          ('doyun', 'Doyun Kim'),
          ('siu', 'Siu Park'),
          ('jill', 'Jill Maggie'),  
        )
    ),
    ('Japan', (  
          ('akari', 'Akari Tanaka'), 
          ('jack', 'Jack Smith'), 
          ('haruto', 'Haruto Nakamura'), 
        ) 
    ),
)
```

Currently my working my working fields looks like this:

```
companies = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=COMPANIES)
managers = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MANAGERS)
```

But for the fidelity of the data, I don't want to repeat the country names twice and possibly have data like this (or something similar):

```
COMPANY_INFO =  (
    ('USA', (
          ('gm', 'General Motors'), 
          ('tesla', 'Tesla'),
          ('ford', 'Ford')
        ), (
          ('jack', 'Jack Smith'), 
          ('doyun', 'Doyun Kim'),
          ('jill', 'Jill Maggie'),
          ('akari', 'Akari Tanaka'),  
        )       
    ),
    ('South Korea', (
          ('kia', 'Kia Motors'),
          ('hyundai', 'Hyundai Motors'),
        ), (
          ('doyun', 'Doyun Kim'),
          ('siu', 'Siu Park'),
          ('jill', 'Jill Maggie'),  
        )
    ),
    ('Japan', (
          ('nissan', 'Nissan Motors'),
          ('honda', 'Honda Motors'), 
          ('toyota', 'Toyota Motors'), 
        ), (
          ('akari', 'Akari Tanaka'), 
          ('jack', 'Jack Smith'), 
          ('haruto', 'Haruto Nakamura'), 
        ) 
    ),
)
```

Two questions:

1) How can I write the `model.Charfield()` so that it will use `COMPANY_INFO`?

```
companies = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=COMPANY_INFO[some magic here])
managers = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=COMPANY_INFO[some other magic here])
```

`COMPANY_INFO` does not have to be a tuple as long as it is accepted by `model.Charfield()`,i.e. following condition is enough:

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of
>   exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for
>   this field.

2) (BONUS) How can I make lookups easily using `COMPANY_INFO`? Specifically, what is the Python code to get answers to questions like: "What are the company abbreviations in USA?", "What is the first and lastname of 'siu'?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can specify this as:

```
COMPANIES = tuple((k, v) for (k, v, __) in COMPANY_INFO)
MANAGERS = tuple((k, v) for (k, __, v) in COMPANY_INFO)
```

So you can define this in your fields like:

```
companies = models.CharField(
    max_length=30,
    choices=tuple((k, v) for (k, v, __) in COMPANY_INFO)
)
managers = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    choices=tuple((k, v) for (k, __, v) in COMPANY_INFO)
)
```

But based on your second question:

> 2) (BONUS) How can I make lookups easily using COMPANY_INFO? Specifically, what is the Python code to get answers to questions like: "What are the company abbreviations in USA?"

I think it might make more sense to make separate models for `Company` and `Manager`. Here your data is static, which can result in some problems if for example you want to *add* a company/mananger, rename one, or remove one.

A `ForeignKey` to models, also easily allows you to query the database, make changes, and store extra data about the company/manager.

`CharField`s with choices are typically used if the choices are *static*: for example the states in the United States are probably quite static (well there have been plans some decades ago to make the Vatican, Great Britain, etc. United States states, but as far as I know, these plans never really took "momentum"). The gender of a person is another one.

But companies and managers have typically a more dynamic nature. What if Doyun Kim no longer is a manager? Or moves to Japan?

Comment: Thanks, the first part is exactly what I was looking for. For the second part, the two tables (Companies, Managers) will be pretty much static and the data will be at most twice as big as the sample data above. I can create two tables as you've suggested. But each will be a table of at most 20 rows. And my main concerns is actually performance, i.e. slow table lookup.  And second minor concern is somewhat more complicated overall model. Do you think adding two additional models (for the sake of easy look ups) will affect the performance?

Comment: @HBat: my own experience is that typically *one* query is not that problematic, it is more the *N+1* problem that is problematic, but with proper `.select_related(..)` and `.prefetch_related(..)` the amount of time for JOINing is normally quite limited.